# My discord.py bot is not starting because of a KeyError

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

With the following code that I have for my bot, he's not booting up. I don't understand.

[Here](https://mystb.in/HeavenPartReid.python) is my code (I have put a mystb.in link, because my question had "too much code")

The full traceback:

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000000004005D30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Bi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\Bi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 711, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\Bi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 504, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

And [here](https://i.postimg.cc/NGVC3qyz/Bot-ne-starte-pas-keyerror.png) is the image of what the error shows up like in VSCode.

There is something that I don't understand very well, when I put in a different token it works just perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I went on replit and the error shew very well : Invalid token.

My bot just got deleted.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the problem lies in reading from the config file in main at lines 6-13. Make sure that in config.json you have all the variables you're trying to get and it gets them correctly.

Comment: In fact, I discovered the issue... The account that created the bot, my main account, got disabled, and it was 1 month ago, exactly, and it got deleted. Discord I hate you...

Comment: @Mr.PRAINGLE: Consider posting [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70734810/my-discord-py-bot-is-not-starting-because-of-a-keyerror/70735014#comment125048131_70735014) as an answer to the question (or upvoting / recommending an existing answer if it resolves the issue)